# Why can't Hashem chase the people out of Canaan quickly?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, eretz-yisrael, animals, mishpatim, ekev

[Exodus 23:29](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9884#v=29) says that Hashem promised not to drive out the indigenous peoples of Canaan too quickly lest the wild animals become too plentiful. This is repeated in [Deuteronomy 7:22](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t0507.htm).  However the previous verse states that Hashem will send hornets to wage the battles for them. I assume Hashem has equal control over hornets and all other animals. So why not chase the people out quickly and keep the animals from overrunning the land?

Comment: HaShem doesnt change nature. it is the nature of animals to roam the lands. people living in those areas fight off/prevent animals from taking over the places.

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYaa3gob And wild hornet attacks are a pretty much daily occurrence?

Comment: no it wasnt everyday. but it wasnt the hornets that kicked them out either. yahoshua3 been nun 3alow sholom waged war on them

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYaa3gob so the verse is referring to...?

Comment: that HaShem will send hornets and we will finish the job?

Comment: @MoriDoweedhYaa3gob so again. Sending hornets is OK but animals reproducing less is not OK? Why is one a deviation from nature which you suggest Hashem won't do (despite much evidence to the contrary in the actual conquest of Israel) but the other is not?

Comment: constricted nature is different than diverting nature for a certain cause

Comment: Ibn Ezra says that the it was to big for Israel to settle with their numbers & that the land would become overgrown doesn't address the question at all!
I think we didn't have man power to conquer the seven nations naturally & needed help from the hornets. Once the land was conquered, open miracles were gonna happen less so we'd learn to live in the regular world & be a light unto it. Engineers won't take advice from a singer. But if a more talented and successful engineer comes along they're all ears. We had to learn to be engineers & relate to the world so that it could look up to us.

Answer (score 3):

[**Ba'al Ha Turim**](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9596&st=&pgnum=393&hilite=) quotes a midrash, saying that Gd knew that Israel would sin and cause His Providence to depart. This would leave them vulnerable to the feral beasts of the field if they conquered the land too quickly. So future sins would keep Gd from preventing the animals from overrunning the land.